# How to avoid MP3 downloading sites from using my files?

Tags: htaccess

I have a WordPress site where I'm gonna host files such as MP3s. The thing is I know if I don't do anything, MP3 Crawlers like mp3glu or mp3pleer will come and use my files and bandwidth, which I don't want (it's a free host, and since he's already kind enough to host me, I don't want to cost him too much, you know).

Now I saw that I could use the htaccess file, but... how ? I currently have this :

```
RewriteEngine on
#Disallow blank:
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?thomaskowalski.net [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|mp3|mp4)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Basically, I wanted to try to say that the pensees thing was not here anymore if the referrer was not my website itself (thomaskowalski.net). Though, it doesn't work. I created a random reddit post so my referrer should not be my site and well it works as if i had done nothing (if whatismyreferrer is right, the referrer is empty)

Any idea ? I precise that the pensees is not a file nor a directory, it's a wordpress network blog, but doing anything else (with a file for example) does the same.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you sure your .htaccess/mod_rewrite is being processed? What you have should prevent "hotlinking", by serving a 403 Forbidden. "the referrer is empty" - By following a link on another site the HTTP referer should not be empty (whatismyreferrer cannot test this?). But anyway, your current rules block an empty referer (the line is commented out). This method only prevents casual "hotlinking". If a site is determined to pull MP3s from your site then it can still do so unless you protect them with some kind of authentication (or start blocking IP addresses).

Comment: Anyway, the goal is to block most of it, it's not to create a super safe music store, it's just a personal blog.

Answer (score 1):

I would not depend on the referrer.

The easiest way is to make a set of rules with IP addresses you want blacklisted as well as user agents you want blacklisted and if a remote user matches any of the blacklists, then they will receive the not-authorized page. Below is a template you can use. replace the set of three x's with digits for the IP address and the slashes are next to the dots to make them literal. Also, change `secretmp3folder` to the folder where your MP3's are stored.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx [OR]
...
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx [OR]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} xxx\.xxx\.xxx\.xxx
RewriteRule ^/secretmp3folder/(.*)$ - [R=403,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^badagent$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^terribleagent$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^insaneagent$
RewriteRule ^/secretmp3folder/(.*)$ - [R=403,L]
```

Another thing you can do is when advertising the download, make the link to it a special page that sets a cookie then redirects the user to the download.

Here's an example. (keep in mind I'm excluding common HTTP headers and I'm only showing content within the body tags)

The advertisement page:

```
<p>Download any of these songs</p>
<a href="download.php?mp3=song1.mp3">Song 1</a><br>
<a href="download.php?mp3=song2.mp3">Song 2</a><br>
```

The download.php script the links link to:

```
<?php
  if (intval($_GET['DOWNLOAD']) != 1){
    $file=$_GET["mp3"];
    setcookie("candownload",1,time()+86400,"/","example.com");
    header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved",true);
    header("Location: http://example.com/path/to/download.php?mp3=".$_GET["mp3"]."&DOWNLOAD=1",true);
  }else{
    if (intval($_COOKIE["candownload"]) != 1){
     echo "Access denied";
    }else{
    header("content-type: application/ms-download",true);
    header("content-disposition: attachment; filename=".$_GET["mp3"],true);
    echo file_get_contents("/path/to/".$_GET["mp3"]);
    } 
  }
?>
```

The script isn't 100% perfect since some things needs tweaking depending on where the MP3 files are on your system. But the idea is when someone clicks a downloadable MP3 file, they are taken to a redirect page and at the same time a cookie is stored on the clients computer to identify them as a client. then after the redirect, the client is validated as a client and the download immediately begins.

Comment: Thanks for this, though, I find it a little too... too much. I mean it's just a blog where I'll sometimes put some music to the visitors to discover, it's not a music store or something, and getting all the IP addresses of the websites I don't want to let access my files seem... difficult. But if nothing else works I'll do it this way.

Comment: Well, looks like it's some Chrome plugin which removes the referer, on Edge whatismyreferer gets it, but it still  doesn't work (see page here : https://www.reddit.com/r/draft/comments/3upiwr/test/)

Answer (score 1):

To stop hotlinking from any website just add this to your htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)example.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|jpeg|bmp|zip|rar|mp3|flv|swf|xml|php|png|css|pdf)$ - [F]
```

more info [Here](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204644230/prevent-hotlinking-with-a-htaccess-file)

UPDATED:
It worked well for me when I hosted mp4 files

UPDATED: this is what I used for my website and it seemed to work well. Other websites could not stream my videos at all. This is not just for blocking other websites to use your files. I just want to show where the bit of code you are looking goes.

```
Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^watch/([^/]+)/? view.php?id=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9_-]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z-]+)/?$ search.php?q=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /search(?:\.php|)\?q=([^\ &]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|mp4)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Comment: Gonna try this...

Comment: It may be a stupid question, but does this apply to the subfolders ? It's a Wordpress site, so the files are in /wp-content/uploads or something like this, not at the root where my .htaccess is.

Comment: There's really no difference between this code and the code posted in the question, except _this_ code is _less_ restrictive by allowing an empty referer. Yes, it _should_ apply to subfolders, unless maybe you have more .htaccess files dotted around? "It's a Wordpress site" - ah, so where are you putting these directives? This will need to go _before_ any WordPress stuff.

Comment: I had it just before rewrite stuff. I will update my answer because the code will look bad in this comment

Comment: I updated my htaccess with the content of yours, and put it before all the WordPress stuff. Still the same :( (see here : http://pastebin.com/fyKJLRhe)

Comment: So how do you know it doesnt work? I tested mines because I had 2 different servers runing and I could not show mp4 files on another one because it was restricted

Answer (score 1):

I once went for a solution which was simple, but effective:

```
// You place this in your index.php
session_start();
$_SESSION['is_user'] = true;

// And this in your download.php:
session_start();
if( isset($_SESSION['is_user']) ){
    // Download magic here
}
```

A crawler often doesn't set a session, and for those that do often don't store it to the next url.